# Drupal 7's default/core search not working

Tags: php, drupal, indexing, drupal-7, cron

Had fulfilled following prerequisites of the Drupal 7's built in search to work:

1. 'Re-index site'.
2. 'Run cron'. (Cron run successfully.)

**Result:** 100% of the site has been indexed. There are 0 items left to index.

**Issue:** The strange behavior is when I search the relevant text (which I'm sure is available), unfortunately got following message every time: 'Your search yielded no results.'

Any idea why the search is not pulling relevant data?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check your user permissions to ensure that it is enabled to be used and viewed whoever you configure to have access to it.

Comment: Exactly which permission you are talking about? At (admin/people/permissions): Under following heading: "Search" - the option "Use search" is selected on "ANONYMOUS USER" as well, and even I'm already log in as: "ADMINISTRATOR", The search result show nothing.

Comment: @DawoodButt I was referring to the admin/people/permissions. Now I know even with it set to anonymous users it's still not working. If you scroll down to the Active Search Modules on the Search settings, can you check if both the options node and user are selected?

Comment: At (admin/config/search/settings) - Under the following heading: "ACTIVE SEARCH MODULES", I had already tried with: Node and User (Both selected) and with: Node only selected as well. Both setting yields no search results.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

Steps to use if you have content on your site and are using the drupal built-in search and not getting any results:

http://www.w3courses.com/drupal-search-not-working-and-does-not-return-any-results

Comment: Thanks! for the sharing, this what I had already tried, during my initial trouble shooting/debugging but no gain.